# Apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that λ is countably additive.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $ \lambda: \mathcal{M} \longrightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be defined by 
    $$\lambda(E)= \int_{E} fd\mu \text{ for each } E \in \mathcal{M}. $$
    Apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that $\lambda$ is countably additive. That is, prove that if $\{E_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a disjoint sequence of measurable sets, then 
    $$\lambda\bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}  \bigg) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda (E_{n}).$$

---

I have attempted this problem for a couple hours and have made insights in the theory but cannot solve this problem.

I know from $\mathbf{Lemma\ 2: }$ If $f \in L^{+}(X,\mathcal{M})$, then there exists a sequence $f_{n}$ of simple functions such that 
          $0 \leq f_{n}(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for $x \in X, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Somehow I have to get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{E_{n}} f_{n}\ d\mu\bigg) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int f_{n}\chi_{E_{n}}\bigg)=?\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f\ d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda (E_{n})$$
However I cannot the logic for =? and don't know how to get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{E_{n}} f_{n}\ d\mu\bigg).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This easily follows from (the union is disjoint):

$$\int_{\bigcup_n E_n} fd \mu = \sum_{n}\int_{E_n} f d \mu$$

which is an easy corollary from the monotone convergence theorem:

Indeed, $$\int_{\bigcup_n E_n} fd \mu = \int_X f I_{\bigcup_n E_n} d \mu = \int_X \sum_n fI_{E_n} d \mu = \sum_n \int _X f I_{E_n} d \mu = \sum_n \int_{E_n} fd\mu$$

where the monotone convergence theorem was used to exchange integral and sum (apply monotone convergence to the partial sums).

Note that the proposition that I made at the beginning of my answer is also true when $f$ also attains negative values.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the picture. I'm still confused as to how MCT came into play and how you extracted the summation. Is there a property I'm missing regarding limits of partial sums?

Comment: Consider $g_n= \sum_{k=1}^n f_n$. Since all $f_n$ are positive, $g_n$ is a positive, increasing sequence of measurable functions. Moreover, $g_n \to \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k$ pointwise. Now, apply monotone convergence theorem. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: I dont see how the fact that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int g_{n} d \mu$ = $ \int \sum_{n}^{\infty}  f_{n} d \mu$ suggests I can take the summation out.

Comment: We have $g_n \to \sum_k f_k$ pointwise. By monotone convergence theorem, $\sum_{k=1}^n \int f_k d \mu = \int g_n d \mu \to \int \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k d \mu$ and the result readily follows as $\sum_{k=1}^n \int f_k d \mu \to \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int f_k d \mu$ and limits are unique.

Comment: Wow Outstanding. Much Obliged!

Comment: Glad I could help!